# Finding date of NAIP orthophoto

Tags: imagery, naip

How or where do I find the date of an NAIP orthophoto, specifically a California NAIP 2016? I need to know when an image was created.

Comment: What's the source of these orthophotos?  That's always the first place to go to for any metadata.

Answer (score 2):

If you downloaded a NAIP county mosaic from USDA's [Geospatial Data Gateway](https://gdg.sc.egov.usda.gov/), it came with a polygon shapefile of the source image extents. The image date is an attribute of each polygon. Otherwise, you should ask the person who provided the data to you.